# How can I put tooltips on a Option Group in Quasar?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I would like to put a CSS tooltip or [QToolTip](https://next.quasar.dev/vue-components/tooltip) on a specific option in a Quasar option group ([QOptionGroup](https://next.quasar.dev/vue-components/option-group)), but I can't seem to figure out if this is even possible. I am using Quasar v2.0.0-beta7 with Vuejs3.

This sample is sort of how I imagined it would work (see option 1):

```
  <q-option-group
    color="secondary"
    type="checkbox"
    v-model="group"
    :options="[
      { label: 'Option 1', value: 'op1', tooltip: 'I wish this would appear when you hover on option 1' },
      { label: 'Option 2', value: 'op2' },
      { label: 'Option 3', value: 'op3' }
    ]"
  />
```

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/98cw4bLs/1/

I tried to dig into the Quasar source code to see what QOptionGroup has in it, but couldn't really find it. Is there any way to do this? I feel like it defeats the purpose of using Quasar if I just end up making my own option group so I can have a tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find an answer in the Quasar forums. The QRadio component does what I wanted:

```
  <q-radio v-model="group" :label="opt.label" color="secondary" v-for="opt in opts" :key="opt.label" :val="opt.value">
    <q-tooltip v-if="opt.tooltip">
      {{opt.tooltip}}
      </q-tooltip>
  </q-radio>
```